# Mixed partial derivative given first and second order derivative

Tags: partial-derivative

If $$ f_x=f_y=f_{xx}=f_{yy}=1$$ at a point, does it imply $$f_{xy}=f_{yx}=1  $$ at that point.

Note this is not a homework problem, it is a question from a book I am reading for which the solution just regards $f_{xy}=f_{yx}=1$ given $ f_x=f_y=f_{xx}=f_{yy}=1$  (Thomas Calculus 12th edition page 832 question 96). So I was wondering if there was a mistake in the question which is, simply forgetting to add $f_{xy}=f_{yx}=1 $ as a premise.

Comment: How about $x+y+(x^2+y^2)/2$ at $(0,0)$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks for the lovely counter example. It's a book mistake  then.